# Shortest way to convert two formulas using associative and commutative steps

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

You have two formulas in which you add $n$ variables.
The variables in the two formulas are the same, but they
may be in a different order and the parenthesis may be different.
As an example I will use the formulas $a + (((c + e) + d) + b)$ and $(d + e) + ((a + b) + c)$.

Because additions is commutative ($a + b = b + a$) and associative ($(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$),
you can prove that these two formulas are the same. In the formulas of the example, this could
be done in this way:

```
a + (((c + e) + d) + b)
commutative
a + (b + ((c + e) + d))
associative
(a + b) + ((c + e) + d)
associative
((a + b) + (c + e)) + d
associative
(((a + b) + c) + e) + d
commutative
d + (((a + b) + c) + e)
associative
(d + ((a + b) + c)) + e
commutative
(((a + b) + c) + d) + e
associative
((a + b) + c) + (d + e)
commutative
(d + e) + ((a + b) + c)
```

This proof contains of 9 steps. But it probably can be done in less steps.
For each combination of two formulas of $n$ variables I want such a proof
that has a minimal number of steps. Only the commutative and associative
steps may be applied, not induction or anything. What algorithm can I use?

The number of formulas of $n$ variables is $\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$,
which gives the list $1, 2, 12, 120, 1680, 30240, 665280, \dots$.

I know that a proof with a minimal number of steps is not always unique.

It may be helpful to display the formulas as a graph, for example, for $n = 3$:

[image: Graph for n=3]

Then for each two vertices in the graph you have to find a shortest path. The red lines are the commutative steps, the blue lines the associative steps. Each set of connected red lines form a [hypercube graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph). Each set of connected blue lines form a [Tamari lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamari_lattice).

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447289/how-to-print-all-possible-balanced-parentheses-for-an-expression

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Algorithms

Comment: To use a shortest path algorithm, you first have to generate a graph. The number of vertices in the graph increases very fast as $n$ gets bigger, so generating the graph will take too much memory and time.

Comment: It is not true you need to generate the whole graph, specially since all edges distances are $1$. You do need to generate neighbors, though. And there are many good algorithms for undirected graph, with unit weights like this one.

Comment: I'd agree with @RGB that you don't need to generate the graph up-front. [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is the obvious algorithm to go for but I can't see any trivial admissible heuristics.

Comment: Alright, maybe I'll give it a try. But I'm convinced there is a simpler and faster algorithm.